# I can't download Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been currently attempting to install Pokemon Go for a while, since yesterday.

I've found to my disappointment that I couldn't find Pokemon Go in the Play Store at all. Even though I'm in Australia, where Pokemon Go is supposed to be released, I can't find it.

I've also attempted a direct APK download from apkmirror, but a strange parsing error has been blocking the installation.

Does anyone else have this problem, and does anyone have a possible solution to it?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: It's rather old. Samsung Galaxy S4

Comment: Android Version 4.3, API level 18

Comment: Afaik it requires Android 4.4

Comment: Missed it by 0.1 D;

Comment: Is it possible if I can update Android OS to 4.4 and try it again? It's one update, so it's probably not a big difference...hopefully

Comment: @MinusReputation Yes I think it will work, tried Pokemon Go on a Nexus5. Doesn't run perfectly but well enough, and afair the hardware specs are similar. I'd give cyanogen mod a try which also promises a better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phone running Android 4.3 makes it incompatible with Pokémon Go. Your best bet is getting a new phone, since the S4 isn't getting newer updates, or using a custom ROM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the APK, you will need to allow unknown sources. This is what causes the "parse error" when you try to install it.
To allow unknown sources, do the following:
Go to Settings > Security. Scroll down until you see "Unknown sources" and switch it on. Press OK when it gives you a warning. Now reopen the APK and it should install fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is updating
If you want(on your own risk), try a custom ROM: https://www.androidpit.com/galaxy-s4-android-update